# SQL - Rounding decimals from a count sum without a column

Tags: mysql, sql, count, decimal, rounding

How can I round the decimals from a count sum without having a column. A column is required in the use of ROUND(), so I am clueless. I'm trying not to create any more columns.

Here is what I have done so far and which works, but it displays too many decimals (4 after the zero). Please note that the reason that the SELECT phrase is in brackets is because it's in another SELECT phrase). What matters is that my code works, but I can't get rid of the decimals...

```
(SELECT (COUNT(v.id) * r.res_cpm/1000)
FROM databasename_viewcounter v
WHERE v.subject_id = r.subject_id) AS cpm_revenue

FROM databasename_resources r 
WHERE r.order_id=:order_id
ORDER BY r.beginning ASC");
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name MySQL + InnoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function CASTS the select statement as `decimal`

```
cast((COUNT(v.id) * r.res_cpm/1000)as decimal (10,2))
```

Comment: I'm trying to get two decimals instead of four, but thanks anyway! :) It's a good solution if you don't want any decimals. I forgot to mention that I need two. My bad.

Comment: then go with `cast((COUNT(v.id) * r.res_cpm/1000)as decimal (10,2))`

Comment: Are those both available in MySQL too and not just MS SQL Server? Can't find my documentation on Cast. Not on w3schools and dev.mysql doesn't have a page for it. Just says "similar to convert" :D Found only this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: cast and convert should be valid for both MS SQL and MySQL